# Entity Framework - Override navigation properties (hook in generating proxy)

Tags: c#, entity-framework-4.1

I recently found a blog discussing about the generated proxy of entity framework when working with POCO. The blogger shows how to see the generated proxy code which is quite interesting.

He also talks about overriding the navigation properties, that is, executing code when there is an access to a navigation property. The problem is that the code seems to be in an image that is not available.

My question is : does anyone knows how to override the navigation properties (hook into the generated proxy) to do something before calling back to entity framework?

---

**Edit**

I am using code-first

Comment: Are you using code-first or the visual EF designer (EDMX with code-generation)? As far as I recall the EDMX code generator generates partial properties that you can simply override/implement as needed.